# Breadth-first traversal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want give every element in a table a generated id. See this html table below:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">A3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B1</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">B3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to give each element an id using breadth-first traversal. So, the result becomes like this:

```
<table>
<tbody id="0">
    <tr id="1">
        <td id="4">A1</td>
        <td id="5">A2</td>
        <td id="6">
            <a href="#" id="13">A3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td id="7">B1</td>
        <td id="8">B2</td>
        <td id="9">
            <a href="#" id="14">B3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
        <td id="10">C1</td>
        <td id="11">C2</td>
        <td id="12">C3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried the `each()` function in jQuery to generate the id for every element in that table, but the traversal algorithm used in `each()` function is pre order traversal.

Can anyone suggest me the Javascript code to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var n = 0
var level = $("table");

while (level.children().length) {
    level = level.children().each(function(_, el) {
        el.id = n++;
    })
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/J5QMK/

---

If you want to avoid the redundant `.children()` call, you can do this:

```
while ((level = level.children()).length) {
    level.each(function (_, el) {
        el.id = n++;
    })
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/J5QMK/1/

Answer (score 5):

A common way to do a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is to use a queue as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var ctr = 0;
    var queue = [];

    queue.push(jQuery("table").children()); // enqueue
    while (queue.length > 0) {
        var children = queue.shift(); // dequeue
        children.each(function (ix, elem) {
            queue.push(  // enqueue
                jQuery(elem).attr("id", ctr++).children();
            );
            console.log(elem.tagName + ": " + elem.id);
        });
    }
});
```